# Google Adsense and Google Analytics make my lighthouse score very low, is there any solution for it?

Tags: pagespeed, lighthouse

I have a web page with both Adsense and Analytics on it.

Just used the normal way to add the related JavaScript code.

However, the Lighthouse score is very low. And I found a significant reason is due to the integration of **Google Analytics** and **Google Adsense**.

Is there any solution/suggestion for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to lazy-loading your script. There are two different ways I provide to you to do this:

**Using setTimeout()**

```
function KJ_AsOT(){var a=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],b=document.createElement("script");b.type="text/javascript",b.src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js",a.appendChild(b)}setTimeout(KJ_AsOT,1500);
```

Set the timeout `1500` to whatever time you want. The larger the number, the more likely this problem is resolved.

**Load on-scroll**

```
var lazyadsense=!1;window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){(0!=document.documentElement.scrollTop&&!1===lazyadsense||0!=document.body.scrollTop&&!1===lazyadsense)&&(!function(){var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript",e.async=!0,e.src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(e,a)}(),lazyadsense=!0)},!0);
```

Load your script when the user has scrolled. This method also makes AdSense ads only load when the user scrolls, so there is a small possibility that this method can reduce your income.

You can apply these methods to Google Analytics as well. Be sure to delete all `https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js` in your HTML before adding the code above.

Comment: Thanks, just wondering, why "1500"? Is there any reference for this number?

Comment: It's the timeout, I set it to 1.5s (1500 ms) because it's good for my website. You can modify it whatever you want.

Comment: Delay the GA is good but delay the adsense would not only affect the income but also the layout. May I know what your website is?